# app won't start after language changed

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I'm testing my app for iOS7 in xcode 5 an the simulator right now. When changing the language setting on the simulator the app closes which seems to be normal. When I try to start the app with the icon again the app will not start anymore. I need to restart the simulator completely.

Is that normal behavior? Unfortunately I can't test the app on the real device right now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it on my ios7 simulator and that won't happen.
You can try it again to find out if it is a rare event.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is a rare event. Could you give an example?

Comment: @JFS I mean it perhaps won't happen usually.

Comment: Ah understood. But unfortunately it happens all the time. So with your comment there must be an issue somewhere. I need to find the root cause now. I never had issues with xcode 4 and its simulator. It just came up with the new xcode 5 simulator. But it might be related to some iOS 7 changes as well. Thanks anyway.